# Kubernetes nginx ingress is not resolving services

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

**Cloud:** Google Cloud Platform.

I have the following configuration

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: api
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api
        image: gcr.io/*************/api
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /_ah/health
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 5
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: api
spec:
  selector:
    run: api
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
---
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: main-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/*
        backend:
          serviceName: api
          servicePort: 8080
```

All set. GKE saying that all deployments are okay, pods number are met and main ingress with nginx-ingress-controllers are set as well. But I'm not able to reach any of the services. Even application specific 404. Nothing. Like, it's not resolved at all.

Another related question I see to entrypoints. The first one through main-ingress. It created it's own LoadBalancer with own IP address. The second one address from nginx-ingress-controller. The second one is at least returning 404 from default backend, but also not pointing to expected api service.

[image]

Comment: be aware that `path:` is not a glob, it is a regex: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#httpingresspath-v1beta1-extensions meaning `/api/*` will match `/api//////` but not `/api/do-the-thing`

Comment: And what happens if you curl to the NodePort for `api` (the :8080 in the first line of your screenshot?)

Comment: 1. Here it is said, that it is just a wildcard pattern match. https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#step_6_optional_serving_multiple_applications_on_a_load_balancer
Also examples using the same approach.

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel, I'm not able to curl api service, as NodePort is in clusters network and not exposed.

Comment: According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/28443#issuecomment-264338660), that it is apparently cloud-provider specific; but for sure the nginx-ingress controller uses [`location ~* /the/path`](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/nginx-0.18.0/internal/ingress/controller/template/template.go#L309) which [according to nginx](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) is case-insensitive(!) regex matching

Comment: Could you please tell the correct URL for your service that responds 200 when accessing ClusterIP with curl?